# ASPxGridView CustomCallback

Tags: asp.net, callback, devexpress, aspxgridview

this is the aspx code for my ASPxGridView

```html
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="dgJournalList" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="dgJournalList" 
    OnCustomCallback="dgJournalList_CustomCallback"
    OnCustomJSProperties="dgJournalList_CustomJSProperties" 
    KeyFieldName="LineNo" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <SettingsPager Visible="False">
    </SettingsPager>
    <SettingsDataSecurity AllowDelete="False" AllowEdit="False" AllowInsert="False" />
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="ItemNo" VisibleIndex ="1" 
            ReadOnly="true" Visible="true">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="PostingDateStr" VisibleIndex ="2" 
            ReadOnly="true" Visible="true">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="EntryTypeStr" VisibleIndex ="3" 
            ReadOnly="true" Visible="true">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="DocumentNo" VisibleIndex ="4" 
            ReadOnly="true" Visible="true">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="LocationCode" VisibleIndex ="5" 
            ReadOnly="true" Visible="true">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Qty" VisibleIndex ="6" 
            ReadOnly="true" Visible="true">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="UOM" VisibleIndex ="7" 
            ReadOnly="true" Visible="true">
        </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
    </Columns>
    <ClientSideEvents EndCallback ="onEndCallback(s, e)" />
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

the function from javascript

```js
onButtonClick = function (args)
{
    switch (args)
    {
        case 'refresh':
            dgJournalList.PerformCallback('Refresh');
            break;
    }
}
```

and the method for callback

```cs
protected void dgJournalList_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    string[] param = e.Parameters.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);
    BOResponse objResponse = new BOResponse();

    switch (param[0])
    {
        case "Refresh":
            objResponse = GetListJournal(null);
            if (objResponse.MsgCode != 0)
            {
                dgJournalList.JSProperties["cpErrMsg"] = objResponse.MsgDesc;
            }
            dgJournalList.DataSource = JournalList;
            dgJournalList.DataBind();
            dgJournalList.FocusedRowIndex = 0;
            break;
        }            
    }
```

When performing the refresh action, my application doesn't call back, doing the postback instead, as, when debugging, the breakpoint at the callback method isn't reached; it's hitting a breakpoint at `Page_Load` method.

Where is my code failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you see is a normal behavior. Postback means complete page reload. Do you observe it your case? Based on the code you've posted you should't. You should see only the grid area reload.

`Page_Init` and `Page_Load` events will be fired after you've called `dgJournalList.PerformCallback('Refresh');` in Javascript. Then the control will be handed to your `dgJournalList_CustomCallback` method.

If you don't want the `Page_Init` and `Page_Load` logic be executed during grid's custom callback, then add the following checks into those event handlers:

```
if (!IsPostBack && !IsCallback)
{
    // your code which is run ONLY at initial page load should be put here
}
```

If you need to run Page_Init and Page_Load code during some button clicks which do cause postback, then remove the `IsPostBack` part from the above condition.

More info on the topic:

1. [ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx) - MS doc
2. [The Concept of Callbacks](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/K18387) - DevExpress doc

Comment: thx mate, good now i understand more about the callbacks or postbacks

Comment: @justamediocorenewbie thanks for the feedback! Up-voted your question so you now have enough rep for voting.

Answer (score 0):

Button AutoPostback property should be false to avoid page postback.

```
<dx:ASPxButton id="btnSave" runat="server" AutoPostback="false"/>
```